# c++ map member validation

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a shared library that uses a map to store different timer ids to eventid mapping...

When I try to get the value, using the below [] operator, the code crashes with signal 11.

```
 long timerId = _timerIdsMap[specifiedEvent];
```

Now, when i change it to the below format,

```
    map<int, long>::iterator EventIterator;
    EventIterator = _timerIdsMap.find( specifiedEvent );

    if(EventIterator!=_timerIdsMap.end())
    {
            // long timerId = _timerIdsMap[specifiedEvent];
            long timerId = EventIterator->second;
            if( _timer.cancel( timerId ) < 0 )
```

The code works perfectly fine.

Assuming that the key is valid in both the cases,Why does the code crash in the first case??I know the second way of acess is the safe one, but Assuming that the key is valid in both cases, why does the code crash in the first way of accessing map using [] operator?

For more info, this is the way map is initialised.

```
bool TimerManager::start_interval_timer( TimerEventHandler* handler, int* specifiedEvent, int sec, int usec, int intervalSec, int intervalUsec)
{
    bool retVal = true;
    int specifiedEventVal = *specifiedEvent;
        long timerId = -1 ;
  _timersMap[specifiedEventVal] = handler;
```

Comment: If the key was valid, it would work just the same.

Comment: The strange thing is it is valid key in both the cases.

Comment: Your second code snippet is *not* initialising the map you're using in the first code snippet.

Comment: This line inserts a member in map, if it doesnot exist. _timersMap[specifiedEventVal] = handler;

Comment: But it's a different map.

Comment: Is `specifiedEvent` in the first case a `int*` or an `int` ? I assume it is `int` but it is a bit confusing.

Comment: I suspect the code shortly after the line below the use of `operator[]`, the place where you are using the zero that results from using `operator[]` on an item that isn't in your map. You haven't shown enough code. You haven't shown you are storing into `_timerIdsMap` (you showed the code for a different map), you didn't show the `else` clause on your iterator alternative, and you didn't show how `timerId` is used. The crash is not coming from the use of `operator[]`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for that code to crash ever. There are no invalid keys in `std::map`. Reading from a map with `operator[]` will always work, it would create and return a default value (here 0) if the element doesn't exist yet. You probably have something else wrong.

Comment: I'm going to guess the problem lies elsewhere and just happens to show up on that line.  If the key doesn't exist in the map it would add a default constructed pair and return the value.